# Can't figure out how to call ohsnap.js

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a simple notification "pop-up", but my dyslexia is my enemy. (Took me 3 hours to find that I've written "scr" instead of "src"

The script itself is a pre-written script (http://justindomingue.github.io/ohSnap/)
This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8>


<link href="//my.site.se/css/ohsnap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="ohsnap"></div>


<script src= "//my.site.se/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="//my.site.se/js/ohsnap.js"></script>

<script>
ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...');
</script>
</body>
```

The last "script" is my last attempt to call the ohsnap function, but I just can't get it to work.

I've checked the html code and are sure that the css and script files are "loaded".

This is the ohsnap.js

```
/**
 * == OhSnap!.js ==
 * A simple jQuery/Zepto notification library designed to be used in mobile apps
 *
 * author: Justin Domingue
 * date: september 18, 2015
 * version: 1.0.0
 * copyright - nice copyright over here
 */

/* Shows a toast on the page
 * Params:
 *  text: text to show
 *  options: object that can override the following options
 *    color: alert will have class 'alert-color'. Default null
 *    icon: class of the icon to show before the alert. Default null
 *    duration: duration of the notification in ms. Default 5000ms
 *    container-id: id of the alert container. Default 'ohsnap'
 *    fade-duration: duration of the fade in/out of the alerts. Default 'fast'
*/
function ohSnap(text, options) {
  var defaultOptions = {
    'color'       : null,     // color is  CSS class `alert-color`
    'icon'        : null,     // class of the icon to show before the alert text
    'duration'    : '5000',   // duration of the notification in ms
    'container-id': 'ohsnap', // id of the alert container
    'fade-duration': 'fast',  // duration of the fade in/out of the alerts. fast, slow or integer in ms
  }

  options = (typeof options == 'object') ? $.extend(defaultOptions, options) : defaultOptions;

  var $container = $('#'+options['container-id']),
    icon_markup = "",
    color_markup = "";

    if (options.icon) {
        icon_markup = "<span class='" + options.icon + "'></span> ";
    }

    if (options.color) {
      color_markup = 'alert-' + options.color;
    }

    // Generate the HTML
    var html = $('<div class="alert ' + color_markup + '">' + icon_markup + text + '</div>').fadeIn(options['fade-duration']);

    // Append the label to the container
    $container.append(html);

    // Remove the notification on click
    html.on('click', function() {
        ohSnapX($(this));
    });

    // After 'duration' seconds, the animation fades out
    setTimeout(function() {
        ohSnapX(html);
    }, options.duration);
}

/* Removes a toast from the page
 * params:
 *    Called without arguments, the function removes all alerts
 *    element: a jQuery object to remove
 *    options:
 *      duration: duration of the alert fade out - 'fast', 'slow' or time in ms. Default 'fast'
 */
function ohSnapX(element, options) {
    defaultOptions = {
      'duration': 'fast'
    }

    options = (typeof options == 'object') ? $.extend(defaultOptions, options) : defaultOptions;

    if (typeof element !== "undefined") {
        element.fadeOut(options.duration, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    } else {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(options.duration, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the css file:

```
/* ALERTS */
/* inspired by Twitter Bootstrap */

.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 21px;
  /* Each alert has its own width */
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.alert-red {
  color: white;
  background-color: #DA4453;
}
.alert-green {
  color: white;
  background-color: #37BC9B;
}
.alert-blue {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4A89DC;
}
.alert-yellow {
  color: white;
  background-color: #F6BB42;
}
.alert-orange {
  color:white;
  background-color: #E9573F;
}
```

And I guess I don't need to attach the jquery  ;)

This is also the fifth script I've been trying today (just tried script has taken over 5 hours), but it won't just work.
I've even tried to read the source code of the makers homepage, but the solution isn't working for me (he uses buttons), I needed the script to be executed as the page is retrieved.

Anybody that have encountered this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your first script tag isn't closed :)

2) You can't declare a function without a name, just use `$(function(){ ... });` to wait for the page to fully load before executing your code.

3) You need to use JQuery, not JQuery Slim in order to use the `.fadeIn()` function properly.

```js
/**
 * == OhSnap!.js ==
 * A simple jQuery/Zepto notification library designed to be used in mobile apps
 *
 * author: Justin Domingue
 * date: september 18, 2015
 * version: 1.0.0
 * copyright - nice copyright over here
 */

/* Shows a toast on the page
 * Params:
 *  text: text to show
 *  options: object that can override the following options
 *    color: alert will have class 'alert-color'. Default null
 *    icon: class of the icon to show before the alert. Default null
 *    duration: duration of the notification in ms. Default 5000ms
 *    container-id: id of the alert container. Default 'ohsnap'
 *    fade-duration: duration of the fade in/out of the alerts. Default 'fast'
*/
function ohSnap(text, options) {
  var defaultOptions = {
    'color'       : null,     // color is  CSS class `alert-color`
    'icon'        : null,     // class of the icon to show before the alert text
    'duration'    : '5000',   // duration of the notification in ms
    'container-id': 'ohsnap', // id of the alert container
    'fade-duration': 'fast',  // duration of the fade in/out of the alerts. fast, slow or integer in ms
  }

  options = (typeof options == 'object') ? $.extend(defaultOptions, options) : defaultOptions;

  var $container = $('#'+options['container-id']),
    icon_markup = "",
    color_markup = "";

    if (options.icon) {
        icon_markup = "<span class='" + options.icon + "'></span> ";
    }

    if (options.color) {
      color_markup = 'alert-' + options.color;
    }

    // Generate the HTML
    var html = $('<div class="alert ' + color_markup + '">' + icon_markup + text + '</div>').fadeIn(options['fade-duration']);

    // Append the label to the container
    $container.append(html);

    // Remove the notification on click
    html.on('click', function() {
        ohSnapX($(this));
    });

    // After 'duration' seconds, the animation fades out
    setTimeout(function() {
        ohSnapX(html);
    }, options.duration);
}

/* Removes a toast from the page
 * params:
 *    Called without arguments, the function removes all alerts
 *    element: a jQuery object to remove
 *    options:
 *      duration: duration of the alert fade out - 'fast', 'slow' or time in ms. Default 'fast'
 */
function ohSnapX(element, options) {
    defaultOptions = {
      'duration': 'fast'
    }

    options = (typeof options == 'object') ? $.extend(defaultOptions, options) : defaultOptions;

    if (typeof element !== "undefined") {
        element.fadeOut(options.duration, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    } else {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(options.duration, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

```css
/* ALERTS */
/* inspired by Twitter Bootstrap */

.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eed3d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 21px;
  /* Each alert has its own width */
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.alert-red {
  color: white;
  background-color: #DA4453;
}
.alert-green {
  color: white;
  background-color: #37BC9B;
}
.alert-blue {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4A89DC;
}
.alert-yellow {
  color: white;
  background-color: #F6BB42;
}
.alert-orange {
  color:white;
  background-color: #E9573F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="ohsnap"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
  ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...', {color: 'red'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, that was a newbie mistake for the last test, it still don't work

Comment: ... But that's a typical dyslexia mistake

Comment: Yes, it says: ReferenceError: ohSnap is not defined

Comment: Solved the reference error, however this error appeared instead:

Comment: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: SyntaxError: function statement requires a name  099.html:19:9
TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function[Läs mer]  ohsnap.js:45:16
 ohSnap https://wearenotalone.se/js/ohsnap.js:45:16
 <anonymous> https://wearenotalone.se/099.html:16:1

Comment: I don't doubt the snippet is working, but I don't know how to get it to display itself, how to execute it.. I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: It is displaying in the snippet man ^^ All I did was replace your anonymous function call by the JQuery `$(function(){ ... });` which waits until the page loads before executing the code.

Comment: Ok, sorry, still don't understand completely, this is the first time I'm using jquery, could you explain to me as I was a complete idiot, (which I feel like right now)  and write the complete correct string I need to use?

Comment: In your HTML, you tried to put your `ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...', {color: 'red'})` inside `function (){ ... }`. You can't do that, you basicly tried to define a function without a name. `$(function(){ ... });` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`, it waits for the page to load before executing your code.

Comment: Okey, but is it necessary to put that inside a function? I've tried without, but no results..            <script>
ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...');

</script>

Comment: If you don't wait for the page to load, some parts of it might not be loaded when you execute your code.

Comment: Oh, I missed the $ sign before function, didn't see that you wrote that.. but $function (ohsnap) {ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...', {color: 'red'}) };     or    $function () {ohSnap('Oh Snap! I cannot process your card...', {color: 'red'}) };    doesn't work either.

Comment: The syntax is : `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Ah, missed the ( after the $, typical dyslexia mistake again, Argh! .. well, I've got that fixed, and now it's not complaining about any scripts error except in the snippet, TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function  ... When loading the page https://wearenotalone.se/099.html  it's still just white, nothing appears on it..

Comment: You need to include JQuery, not JQuery slim : `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Ahh dam!  Of course would the jquery be the wrong version,  it works now! merci beaucoup! If you post that as an answer I can mark it!

Comment: Just mark the original answer as your answer, everything is updated in the snippet :)